# Balanced Snowball Sampling

Tags: statistics, sampling

There is a method in qualitative research called "balanced snowball sampling", which runs as follows. Say the interviews are assessing perspectives on some issue, each interviewee is asked to recommend two further interviewees, one who will offer a more positive perspective, and one who will offer a more negative perspective than their own.

In a simple model of this we are sampling some continuous distribution $p(x)$. However, we are not allows to sample $p(x)$ directly: instead we start from some arbitrary initial sample of a single point (not necessarily drawn from $p(x)$, but necessarily within its support), and the only allowed mechanism for growing the sample size is take some point $x_i$ in our sample, and generate two additional points $x_j^>$ and $x_j^<$ drawn randomly from $p(x|x>x_i)$ and $p(x|x<x_i)$ respectively.

Interestingly, if you apply this method recursively (generating two points from every point in your sample, and two points from each of those points, and so on), the sample distribution does converge, but not to $p(x)$. Instead, the sample distribution over represents tail events.

I have two questions:

1. What distribution does the sample converge to?
2. Is there a straightforward way of including a rejection (discarding
   certain points from the sample) which means that the sample does
   converge to $p(x)$?

Comment: Various comments: A. [searching Google for "balanced snowball sampling"](https://www.google.com/search?q="balanced+snowball+sampling") tuns up only [one other example of this phrase](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0959378021001242) though that does claim to have two citations for the phrase.

Comment: B. How do you know the sample distribution converges to a distribution but do not know what it converges to?  I.e. what is the context of your question and what have you already found?

Comment: C. You may as well assume the original distribution is uniform on $[0,1]$ and see, for example initially by simulation, what sort of shape either the CDF or density converges too.  I have done the simulation and I am reasonably confident I can spot the limiting distribution (similar curves come up in other contexts), though I have not yet gone to the effort of proving it.  You could then use a quantile function (inverse of the CDF) to apply this to any continuous distribution.

Comment: D. Do you want a rejection scheme which chooses some of the full sample deterministically or take a weighted subsample?  An alternative might be to use the full sample but weight the responses in later analysis.

Comment: @Henry A. Ok? B. Numerical simulations show convergence for a bunch of $p(x)$. C. Sure, if $p(x)$ is $U(0,1)$, then the sample distribution is $q(x) = 1/\pi\sqrt{x-x^2}$. I don't see what we learned beyond the intuition I gave above, that it overweights the extremes. We didn't learn a general relationship between $p$ and $q$. This doesn't answer my question so I don't know why I would want to include it, it is more for people to read. D. Weighted sample is ok, if it answers the question. But really I would want a rejection scheme. There is a cost to collecting data, which I want to minimise.

Comment: I like math stack exchange because I like to discuss what I think are fun math problems with a like-minded community of interested folks, especially interesting are ones where the problem is simple, but the techniques for solving it are not obvious to me. It seems harmless to ask, and my asking obliges no one to respond. Nevertheless, it is not uncommon to get comments which read with a little bit of a tone of criticism, as if I am stealing people's time, like some college kid asking people to do my homework for free. Am I misunderstanding the comments? or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: My apologies if my initial comments came across as critical.  This is an interesting question, but it was not clear to me what you had tried (in particular your *"the sample distribution does converge, but not to $p(x)$. What distribution does the sample converge to?"* makes it sound like some other people's questions which reflect their homework).  So I was trying to discover what you had already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you on the answer to C, when starting from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, is an [arcsine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution), i.e. a beta distribution with parameters $\frac12,\frac12$ with density $\frac1{\pi \sqrt{x(1-x)}}$, and Cumulative Distribution Function $\frac2\pi \arcsin(\sqrt{x})$, and quantile function $\sin^2\left(\frac\pi 2 p\right)$. It is not difficult to prove this is stable (assuming a value drawn from this distribution, its two descendents have a joint distribution equal to that of the minimum and maximum of two i.i.d. values from this distribution) though it is a slightly harder to show it must therefore be the limiting distribution.

I think that gives potential approaches to D in general: rank the responses in your full sample $x_{(1)},  x_{(2)},  \ldots, x_{(n)}$ and give them weights based on their position in the arcsine distribution, such as $w_{(i)} =\sin\left(\frac{i-\frac12}{n} \pi\right)$.

Then you can either use all the sample observations with these weights or accept each $x_{(i)}$ with probability $w_{(i)}$ or reject with probability $1-w_{(i)}$. This should get you close to a sample from the original distribution.

Although the weights come from an arcsine distribution, the values you apply them to can come for any continuous distribution for a random variable $X$, as the generation of new values is  related to the distribution of $F(X)$ and that uniform on $[0,1]$.

---

As an illustration, here is an arbitrary simulation from an exponential distribution with rate $2$ (any other continuous distribution would do, changing the first two lines of the code):

```
F    <- function(x){ pexp(x,2) } # actual distribution CDF
Finv <- function(x){ qexp(x,2) } # actual distribution quantile
start <- 0.1234 # arbitrary starting point in support 
numberofrounds <- 15 # full sample size will be 2^(numberofrounds+1) - 1

set.seed(2024)
latest <- start 
fullsample <- latest
for (r in 1:numberofrounds){
  latest <- c(Finv(runif(2^(r-1), 0, F(latest))), 
              Finv(runif(2^(r-1), F(latest), 1)))
  fullsample <- c(fullsample, latest)
  }    
plot.ecdf(fullsample)
curve(F(x), from=min(fullsample), to=max(fullsample), col="pink", add=TRUE)
```

As you say, the full sample (black ECDF below) does not match the underlying distribution (pink) and it oversamples in the tails.

[image]

Select from that, weighting towards the centre:

```
fullsize <- length(fullsample)
sortsample <- sort(fullsample)
probselect <- sin((((1:fullsize)-1/2)/fullsize) * pi)
selectsample <- sortsample[runif(fullsize) < probselect]
plot.ecdf(selectsample)
curve(F(x), from=min(fullsample), to=max(fullsample), col="pink", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

which seems to give a much better fit, with the pink and black curves close to identical. It uses almost $64\%$ of the original full sample values. Essentially the same thing would happen with any other continuous distribution, and you can do the rejection sampling without needing to know what that distribution is (even if you do need the distribution for simulation purposes).

Comment: This great actually. Let me check that I understand. I see your argument as noting that (i) that the answer is pretty straightforward to write down in the $U(0,1)$ case and (ii) this applies in the general too, as every case is related to the $U(0,1)$ case by a variable transformation that preserves ordering. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes: the key point is that the variable transformation is the distribution CDF (and its inverse to reverse this) and applying the CDF of the distribution of a continuous random variable to that random variable gives  a random variable uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks so much!